# Api Blueprint and long running jobs

Tags: json, api, rest, apiblueprint

I would like to properly design my json API with [long running jobs](http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs/) with [Blueprint](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint). 
I need to process files, return a `202 Accepted` with a location header and then design the temporary location who will receive `303 See Other` and then the final object `201 Created`.

Is there a way to properly design this sequence ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The blueprint could look like this:

```
# Stars [/stars]

Collection of stars.

## Create [POST]
+ Request (application/json)

    Create a star

    + Body

            {"name": "Death Star"}

+ Response 202

    Request has been accepted into the queue. Poll the queue item to check the result. 

    + Headers

            Location: /queue/12345


# Queue Item [/queue/{id}]

One item in a job queue.

+ Parameters
    + id: 12345 (number) - Id of the queue

## Query Status [GET]
+ Response 200 (aplication/xml)

    The job is still in progress.

    + Body

            <response>
                <status>PENDING</status>
                <eta>2 mins.</eta>
                <link rel="cancel" method="delete" href="/queue/12345" />
            </response>

+ Response 303

    The job has finished. See the created resource.

    + Headers

            Location: /stars/97865
```